# How would I determine that an S3 bucket and key is accessible to a redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to determine if there is a connection from a redshift cluster is possible between a S3 bucket+key and a redshift cluster. Additionally I would love to find out if it has read and/or write priviledges to the bucket.

Where would I look to find this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the setup is already there and you just want to look around and find out whether access is there.
Typically, cross service access is done using IAM roles, so by checking roles defined on your s3 bucket you should be able to check this.

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html

Hope it helps.